# Set PHP Variables for Drupal 7 Theme Files

Tags: drupal, variables, themes

I want to set custom php variables that can be used throughout my drupal theme (html.tpl.php, page.tpl.php etc.) I need the variables set based on the $title of the node. I'm not an expert on how Drupal works, the moduling and hooks, and I just need to know the simplest/easiest way to accomplish this. I keep reading about implementing some sort of hook in the template.php file where you can set variables, but I've been unsuccesful with everything I've tried.

So, basically, how would you accomplish this:

1. Get $title of Node
2. Set variables that will be passed along into theme files (for example, to do basic things like: if($title == 'news_page') { $siteSection = "news"; } )
3. Have $siteSection be available to use in theme files

Any help would be great.. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Before Drupal builds the HTML for a page from a theme's template (.tpl.php file), it runs preprocess "hooks". Hooks are basically a naming convention for functions that let modules and themes override or "hook" onto Drupal core processes.

E.g., if you want to display a message to a user when they log in, you can use [`hook_user_login`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_login/7).

```
function MODULENAME_user_login(&$edit, $account) {
  drupal_set_message("Welcome, ". $account->name);
}
```

When a user logs in, Drupal looks for all loaded functions that end in "_user_login" and it runs them. If this function is in an enabled module, it has been loaded, so it will get run as well.

If you want to make a variable named `$site_section` available in your `page.tpl.php` file, you can hook into [`template_preprocess_page`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7). This is a theme hook, so the name is a little different, but it functions pretty much the same way. To call this hook from your theme, you need to create a file called `template.php` in your theme's directory. Inside `template.php`, we'll add:

```
<?php
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$vars){
  switch (drupal_strtolower($vars['node']->title)) {
  case "about page":
    $site_section = "about";
    break;
  case "news page":
  case "news page1":
  case "news page2":
    $site_section = "news";
    break;
  default:
    $site_section = "none";
    break;
  }

  $vars['site_section'] = $site_section;
}
```

The `<?php` is used to tell the server the treat all of the proceeding code as PHP. We then declare our hook function with the intention of loading Drupal's array of page variables into a local variable called `$vars`. By adding the `&` before `$vars`, we'll be allowed to modify the values for use outside of this function.

The switch statement will let us efficiently test the page title for multiple values. The value of the node's title may contain uppercase letters, lowercase letters, and symbols, so to avoid a case-sensitive mismatch, we're going to convert the title to lowercase and only test that (symbols will still be in the title, though). After the switch statement, we set the value of our `$site_section` local value into the referenced `$vars` array for use in `page.tpl.php`.

However, if it's just your intention to break the site up into sections for theming purposes, there are other ways of accomplishing that. [My answer to a similar situation a few months ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11408278/169450) might be helpful.